# Bootstrap nav bar with sub menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap and I'm trying to create a nav-bar that look like this

[image]

And when you resize the browser to smaller size its look like this

[image]

Currently what I tried is:

```
<div id="top-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="navbar-header">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BiddingTool</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="../${ usertype }/projects.do"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i> Projects</a></li>
            <c:if test="${ usertype eq 'admin' }">
                <li><a href="../admin/database.do"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Database</a></li>
            </c:if>
        </ul>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="../${ usertype }/projects.do"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i> Projects</a></li>
                <c:if test="${ usertype eq 'admin' }">
                    <li><a href="../admin/database.do"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Database</a></li>
                </c:if>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right: 5px;">
                <li><a href="../logout.do"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /.Navigation Bar -->
```

For working example look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/J629k/)

But the result is far from what I expected

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/programmer101/meR73/) out. Hope this helps.

I've used `row-fluid` class so the `span` class wont have fix width. I've used `span` to divide the divs.

Comment: The button for collapse doesn't work on 2nd time click

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to add the class ".col-sm-" or ".col-xs-".

You can check at [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)